# How ruby compares two dates(or any other objects)

Tags: ruby, comparison

I have a single line code, but it causes me a lot of questions.

The code:

```rb
Time.at(100).send(:>=, Time.at(200))
```

The main question: where the implementation of the `:>=` operator is located?

From what I can see in sources, there is no implementation of `:>=` operator in [`time.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/time.c). Or it is? How to know which method from there implement `:>=`? In the documentation is described only one method for comparing: [<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Time.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), but it's definitely unclear how the call from `:<=>` is translated to `:>=`. Please describe the call trace how the `:>=` is gets called on c-level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>=` method is defined in the [`Comparable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Comparable.html) module. Quote from the docs:

> The Comparable mixin is used by classes whose objects may be ordered. The class must define the `<=>` operator, which compares the receiver against another object, returning a value less than 0, returning 0, or returning a value greater than 0, depending on whether the receiver is less than, equal to, or greater than the other object. If the other object is not comparable then the `<=>` operator should return nil. Comparable uses `<=>` to implement the conventional comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, and `>`) and the method between?.

And the [`Time`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Time.html) Class includes the `Comparable` module.

Comment: Ok, I can see that. But the funny fact... I am still unable to find the implementation of comparison. That method rely actually on some `WIDEVAL_GET` implementation, but that one is simply missing: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/search?q=WIDEVAL_GET , so I still don't know how ruby compare two dates....

Comment: angel, you can confirm that `Time` includes `Comparable`: `require 'time'; Time.included_modules #=> [Comparable, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, Kernel]`

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby `x.y(...)` is equivalent to `x.send(y, ...)` but things like `x + y` also end up being converted into `x.send(:+, y)`. Most operations end up being method calls on some kind of object.

The `>=` operator is a syntax element, but it's effected by calling the `>=` method on the left-side element. That is this code:

```rb
Time.at(100).send(:>=, Time.at(200))
```

Where `:>=` is the Symbol representing `>=`, though you can also use `'>='` instead, even if it's less efficient due to the String overhead.

In any case this is equivalent to just using the operator directly:

```rb
Time.at(100) >= Time.at(200)
```

Which is to say there is no `:>=` operator at all. It's the `>=` operator *represented by* the `:>=` Symbol.

A lot of Ruby's internals in the mainstream ["MRI" version of Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI) are implemented in C for performance reasons. This means you can't readily discover where the method is implemented:

```rb
Time.method(:>=).source_location
# => nil
```

This is because there's no Ruby code involved, it's an "internal" C function instead.

It's worth noting that you don't have to implement methods like `>=` directly, there are short-cuts where these are automatically derived, where in particular [Comparable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Comparable.html) does this for you if a `<=>` method is defined:

> Comparable uses `<=>` to implement the conventional comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, and `>`) and the method `between?`.

In other words you get those all for free if you implement `<=>` and `include Comparable` in your class. Does Time include Comparable? That's easy to find out:

```rb
Time.ancestors
# => [Time, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

It does.

So looking for a specific `>=` method is a lost cause, it's automatically generated.

The way Ruby C extensions are defined is by writing C code and then bridging the methods through using bindings like this:

```c
rb_define_method(rb_cTime, "<=>", time_cmp, 1);
```

Where that associates the `time_cmp()` function with the `rb_cTime` class representation. You can find the source for that function in the file as well.

Comment: Thanks. I found that, but still unable to find the implementation of that comparison as it relys on some WIDEVAL_GET function, and its implementation is missing in the sources...

Comment: Added an example with that specific method.

Comment: @msangel: It's not a function and it's also not missing. That function-like macro is defined [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_0_0/time.c#L260).